# Isn't the JavaScript Notificaiton API useless at this point?

Tags: javascript, notifications

So I read on MDN that the Notification API can only be used on an event initiated by the user. Doesn't this take away any need for this API at all? I can't think of any situation whatsoever where posting a Notification would ever be useful within a user event.

User hits a button: "Hey user, you hit a button! I'm telling you something you already know in the most obnoxious way possible! Hee hee. ^_^"

Are they just deprecating this, or is there still some functionality to it? Am I missing something?

I want to use it to actually notify the user that a note-worthy change has occurred in the state of the application. This is apparently now not a supported use case. Huzzah!

**Update:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Quote: "Note: In the above example we spawn notifications in response to a user gesture (clicking a button). This is not only best practice — you should not be spamming users with notifications they didn't agree to — *but going forward browsers will explicitly disallow notifications not triggered in response to a user gesture. Firefox is already doing this from version 72, for example.*"

Comment: *"So I read on MDN that the Notification API can only be used on an event initiated by the user."* - are you sure? Where did you read this?

Comment: I dont think this is correct. Websites do have ask permission to be able to do notifications, but once they have permission, they can notify outside of user interaction. I use the API to notify after long running web worker tasks on a toy project. Please cite where you saw that it has to originate from a user interaction.

Comment: I think I misread it. Read ceejayoz's answer below. The Notification API just doesn't work for me. ???

Comment: To those who closed this question: It is not opinion-based at all. I just added some color to my question because of my absolute frustration with this feature. But the core of its absolutely factual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misread MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

> Because of abuses of push notifications in the past, web browsers and developers have begun to implement strategies to help mitigate this problem. **You should only request consent to display notifications in response to a user gesture (e.g. clicking a button).** This is not only best practice — you should not be spamming users with notifications they didn't agree to — but going forward browsers will explicitly disallow notification permission requests not triggered in response to a user gesture. Firefox is already doing this from version 72, for example, and Safari has done it for some time.

This only affects the *initial prompt* to allow notifications.

[image: A screenshot of the notifications prompt]

Subsequent *uses* of the Notifications API (once the user selects 'allow') don't require user interactions.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I am already doing that. I have a "Enable Notifications" button on my UI. I don't know. It doesn't seem to matter what browser I use. I make sure I get user permissions, when I test this I make sure I have permissions explicitly. `new Notification("What's up.")` never works no matter what I do. The sample code from MDN does not work in an HTTPS served web page.

Comment: Frankly, sounds like you might have hit “never allow” at some point. Check your browser settings.

Comment: Of course, I checked that. My browser settings are set to "always ask" and the URL for my test is set to "accept". Still nothing. Unless my shop has some policy that in some other way, prevents notification which I would not put past them, I have no idea why I can't get this to work. But at the same time, I do get notified by other web apps.

Comment: How about another browser?

Comment: Works on FIreFox. That's good news, I guess. My App is here: https://whatnext.munroesoft.com

Answer (score -3):

There is a use such as you can make it say stuff you don't know, for example if you forgot your first passkey then you type in your second passkey to see your first passkey, or you can make it say something secret with it in some secretive game such as a ARG.